# Supremum set with odd and even numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For every $n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 3$ find $\limsup B_{n}$ and $ \limsup B_{n}$ when:

$B_{n}=\begin{cases}
\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right) & \text{for n odd}\\
\left(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right) & \text{for n even}
\end{cases}$

I think that $\limsup B_{n} = [0,1] $ and  $\liminf B{n} = (0,1)$ but I'm not sure how to prove it formally.

Can someone provide a book with a basic intro and exercises like this one? I tried to find books that related to "Set limit theory" but with no luck.

Comment: Start by making sure that you understand the definition of $\mathrm{limsup}$ and $\mathrm{liminf}$. Then write down the first couple of $B_n$ - to get a feeling for this sequence. Finally show us your work. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Let set

- $U_n=(-\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n)$
- $V_n=(\frac 1n,1-\frac 1n)$.

The first thing to notice is the monotonicity of these sequences.

$[0,1]\subset\cdots\subset U_{n+1}\subset U_n\ \searrow\qquad$ thus $(U_n)_n$ converges.

$V_{n}\subset V_{n+1}\subset\cdots\subset(0,1) \nearrow\qquad$ thus $(V_n)_n$ converges.

If we have proved $U_n,V_n$ convergence we have not established their limit explicitly.

We know $\begin{cases} V_n\to \mathtt V & \text{ and } & \mathtt V\subset(0,1)\\U_n\to \mathtt U & \text{ and } & [0,1]\subset\mathtt U\end{cases}$

We still have to show the reciprocal inclusions.

$u\in U\implies \forall n\ :\  -\frac 1n<u<1+\frac 1n\implies 0\le u\le 1\implies u\in [0,1]$

$x\in(0,1)\implies \exists \epsilon>0\ \mid [x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]\subset(0,1)\implies x\in(\epsilon,1-\epsilon)\subset V_n\ ,\ \forall n\ge \lceil \frac 1\epsilon\rceil+1\\\phantom{x\in(0,1)}\implies x\in\mathtt V$

Now that we have limits $\mathtt U=[0,1]$ and $\mathtt V=(0,1)$ let's go back to the initial question about $(B_n)_n$

Notice that $V_i\subset U_j$ for any $(i,j)$.

The sequence $B_n$ is as follow : $\quad V_{2n},U_{2n+1},V_{2n+2},U_{2n+3},V_{2n+4},U_{2n+5},\cdots$

- at $2n$ mark, $\sup=U_{2n+1}$ and $\inf=V_{2n}$
- at $2n+1$ mark, $\sup=U_{2n+1}$ and $\inf=V_{2n+2}$

The clean statement is $\begin{cases}\inf\{B_i\mid i\ge n\}=V_{2\lceil\frac n2\rceil}\\\sup\{B_i\mid i\ge n\}=U_{2\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor+1}\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} B_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} V_n=\mathtt V\\\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} B_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} U_n=\mathtt U\end{cases}$